# Log4j2 SMTP to Office365

Tags: java, smtp, office365, log4j2

I am trying to send my error logs via mail using Log4j2. However I have problems connecting to office365.

My configuration looks like this:

```
<SMTP name="Mail" subject="Worker Error" to="recipient@domain.com" from="error@domain.com"
      smtpHost="smtp.office365.com" smtpPort="587" smtpUsername="error@domain.com" smtpPassword="mypassword"
      smtpProtocol="smtp" bufferSize="512" smtpDebug="true">
</SMTP>
```

And this is the error I get.

```
EHLO 192.168.1.106
250-VI1PR02CA0004.outlook.office365.com Hello [80.110.25.16]
250-SIZE 157286400
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-STARTTLS
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250 CHUNKING
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "157286400"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "BINARYMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<error@domain.com>
530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM
DEBUG SMTP: got response code 530, with response: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM
```

I tried changing the protocol to smtps as I thought it might require TLS, but it can't even connect.

```
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.office365.com", port 587, isSSL true
2015-10-20 10:51:24,625 main ERROR Error occurred while sending e-mail notification. javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.office365.com, port: 587;
nested exception is:
     javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Stick with smtp, and add this to your initialization code:

```
import java.util.Properties;
...    
Properties p = System.getProperties();
p.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```